# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2, angular4, angular5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, как решить проблему? Получаю ошибку, когда генерирую сборку и переношу её на сервер. Я уже читал статьи, менял `basehref`, добавлял

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
```

писал `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none --base-href /`
и так `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none`

Но всё-равно получаю ошибку.
В чём может быть дело?

Comment: У тебя скорее всего сервер отправляет по запросу .js файлов, страницу с 404в формате .xml.

Comment: Если клиентское приложение ожидает json, а ему подсовывают html/xml, то будет именно такая ошибка